# Ubuntu 14 Idle - Non Activity Causes Poor Performance

Tags: performance, cpu, system, idle

I'm having an issue with Ubuntu 14. I have a touch screen and I noticed after medium to long periods of inactivity the device "throttles down" and takes a few moments to snap back. When I tap the screen, it takes awhile for it to respond then any subsequent tap is very responsive. From looking around on the forums I ensured my CPUs are set to "performance" instead of "ondemand". Are there any other things I should be looking at to ensure the device maintains peak performance even through long periods of activity?